Keras EarlyStopping Callback Stopping Condition?
I am using the the Keras Early Stopping Callback with the intention of stopping training when the training loss does not improve for 10 consecutive epochs. My code and training results are below: 
It seems like the training was stopped early even though the loss did not exhibit no improvement for 10 consecutive epochs which was what my interpretation was of how EarlyStopping would work from the Keras documentation. Am I misunderstanding something or maybe my code is  wrong?

This looks indeed strange and not how I expect it to work. What Keras (and TF) version are you using? Also, please do not post code as images, the reason.

I am using keras 3.3.2 and TF 2.15. Thanks for the note about posting code as images, I'll avoid doing it in the future. Unfortunately I don't have this source code anymore so I can't fix it for this post now.

I tested a small dummy net with dummy data and approx. your loss magnitude (90k train mse loss, which went up and down) with your callback with TF 2.15/Keras 2.15 and TF 2.15/Keras 3.3.2 on colab, and could not replicate your results.

That's interesting. I'm not sure what else to do, but thanks for giving it a shot
